# Symfony2 Many-To-Many Unidirectional auto create relations

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a ManyToMany relation between `Document` and `Tag` entities, but I can't persist a `Document` when adding new  `Tag`'s

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

That's the error I'm getting, I'm trying to use SelectizeJS to create tags, and this is my mapping stuff for `Document`

```
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $tags
 */
public function addTag($tag)
{
    $this->tags->add($tag);
}
```

And

```
<many-to-many field="tags" target-entity="Foo\Bar\Entity\Tag">
    <join-table name="academy_document_tags">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="tag_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </join-columns>
        <inverse-join-columns>
            <join-column name="document_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </inverse-join-columns>
    </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

I'm using this to create my forms

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tags', new TagsType(), array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'input-tags'
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

`TagsType` has a DataTransformer

```
class TagsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new TagsTransformer());
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foo\Bar\Entity\Tag'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foobar_tag';
    }
}


class TagsTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($tags)
    {
        $tags = $tags->toArray();

        if (count($tags) < 1)
            return '';
        else
            return implode(',', $tags);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        $tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $tagsArray = explode(',', $string);

        if (count($tagsArray) > 0)
            $tags = new ArrayCollection($tagsArray);

        return $tags;
    }
}
```

The idea is to have `Tag` entity with only `id`, `name` and `slug` fields, because I want to use other entities with ManyToMany relations with Tag, so using bidirectional is not a choice.

I don't know where is my error, maybe when doing `addTag($tag)`, I've debugged it and everything seems correct, it's passing a new element to the `ArrayCollection` item...

Comment: How do you create/populate Tag objects? And how does Tag Entity look like? May be you should use ModelTransformer instead?

Comment: @xurshid29 Tag entity has only id, name and slug fields, nothing more because it's an unidirectional relation. I do not populate it throught Document entity/form that's why I am asking how to achieve it. I've tried with cascade=persist inside document ManyToMany relation but nothing hapens.

Comment: are you sure `TagsType` is creating/instantiating valid object?

Comment: Did you look at questions:
[stackoverflow-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606495/warning-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object)
[stackoverflow-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727497/warning-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-with-message)

Comment: @TurdalievNursultan Now I have, but doesn't help me. xurshid29 It wasnt instantiating anything, that was my error. I will post an answer in the next hours with the correct code which can be reused for any case like this ^^